# I've tried reinstalling ms office and also installed office tool runtime. I'm still getting this error while exporting data to an excel file

Tags: c#, excel-interop, badimageformatexception

System.BadImageFormatException: 'Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 800700c1  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1).'
I'm getting this error while running this code to export from data grid view to an excel file. I've tried every solution in stackoverflow but nothing's working. I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.[this shows no matter what i change.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUyDG.png)

Comment: Try setting the platform to x86 instead of Any CPU and then rebuilding.

Comment: @itsme86 i tried doing that but it's still not working.

Comment: Do you have 64-bit Excel installed? Does it work if you change the platform to x64?

Comment: I've tried changing it to x86, x64 and Any CPU. Neither of them work.

Comment: Is your Windows 64 bits and your Excel / Office 32 bits?